# Error while installing lm-sensors

Tags: 20.04, temperature, error-handling, lm-sensors

While installing `lm-sensors` (to check CPU temperature) package in ubuntu , i was getting this error message:

```
sirjan@sirjan-MY32BBZ7A:~$ sudo apt-get install lm-sensors
sudo apt-get --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 292 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up lm-sensors (1:3.6.0-2ubuntu1) ...
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
dpkg: error processing package lm-sensors (--configure):
 installed lm-sensors package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 lm-sensors
^C
sirjan@sirjan-MY32BBZ7A:~$
```

Please note that i had to press `^C` to exit `apt-get` otherwise it just hangs in there.
What does this error message mean? How can i solve it?
I am using Ubuntu 20.04 (Focal Fossa).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reboting the computer, solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to **Synaptic Package Manager** and manually remove then re-install the lm-sensors package (and any dependencies).
Also check the result of `sudo dpkg --configure -a`